# Use primary keys as constructor parameter (Hibernate-tool)

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I used Hibernate generator to create Hibernate Java class and `*.hbm.xml` files. I need a base file and concrete file for the hibernate objects so I followed the instructions in this [link](http://www.4byte.cn/question/321590/hibernate-code-generation-create-abstract-concrete-model-class-pairs.html). The generation was successful but I had two concerns.

1. When I run the generator using BaseStrategy, it also creates a java file for the composite primay key of the table

   Example: I have table1 (id1, id2, field1, field2) primary key(id1,id2).

   The generator creates one java file for the the whole table and one java file for id: (table1base.java, table1id.java) but I only need one BaseFile.
2. I only need primary key as parameter for the BaseFile constructor. When I checked the table1base.java, the cinstructor is like below:

   ```
   public table1(String id1, String id2, String field1, String, field2)
   ```

   I need to use composite primary key ONLY for the constructor parameter.

   I found out that this constructor is created at hibernate-templates>>pojo>>pojoConstructor.ftl

   ```
   public ${pojo.getDeclarationName()}(${c2j.asParameterList
   (pojo.getPropertyClosureForMinimalConstructor(), jdk5, pojo)}) {
       <#if pojo.getDeclarationName()?ends_with("Base")>
           <#foreach field in pojo.getPropertiesForMinimalConstructor()>
           this.${field.name} = ${field.name};
           </#foreach>
       <#else>
       super(${c2j.asArgumentList(pojo.getPropertyClosureForMinimalConstructor())});        
       </#if>
   }
   ```

   *pojo.getPropertyClosureForMinimalConstructor* method get the fields to be put in constructor. Is there any mehthod that will get the primary key only?

Hope I explained it well. Thank you for the replies. Sorry I could not post any code.

Comment: I don't understand. First you say that you don't want a class to be generated for the compsite ID (although you obviously need one), then you says that this class, that shouldn't be generated, should be used as argument of the constructor of the entity. That's contradictory.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry for the confusion. I am required to create Hibernate object same as the existing ones on my project. There is one base class and one concrete class. There is no class specific for the composite id. One of constructor of the base class is the composite primary key and then there are getters and setters for other fields. Having separate class for the primary keys will be redundant. Thanks.

Comment: If you already have the classes, what's the point of recreating them?

Comment: There are existing hibernate objects for old tables. I add new tables so I need to create hibernate objects as well with the same format as old tables' hibernate objects.